# How to get the path of a current running script file?

Tags: linux, proc, shebang

Knowing that program's PID， I want to list out the executable file of a running program.

For binary programs, I can read `/proc/$pid/exe`, which is a symlink to the executable.

However for scripting programs, for example a Python program, `/proc/$pid/exe` points to `/usr/bin/python`, not the program itself. This happens no matter I started the program with `./program.py` or with `python program.py`.

I tried several ways to solve it:

`/proc/$pid/cmdline` contains the filename of the script, but it is in relative path and the working directory may have changed already.

I also tried `/proc/$pid/comm` but it can be easily changed by the program.

So how to know the original script file of a running program?

Comment: `echo 'puts "what script file?"' | ruby -`

Comment: `ps -ef | grep "$pid"` should give you the full command for the process including what script is being run and what options were given. But the output is dependent on what is running and how it was called. Don't know if this will answer your question so posting as comment.

Comment: @Munir `ps -ef` is the same as `/proc/$pid/comm`. The problem is the filename is relative path, not absolute path.

Comment: @StarBrilliant They are not the same...Example - I have `tuned` running on my RHEL server as PID 16865. `ps -ef` gives me `/usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/tuned -d -c /etc/tuned.conf` but `cat /proc/16865/comm` just says `tuned`.

Comment: @Munir It's my typo. I meant `/proc/$pid/cmdline`. It's `cmdline` instead of `comm`.

Answer (score 1):

Can we assume the files are not changed on disk (at least, no files with the same name added or deleted) and `/proc/[pid]/cmdline` is reliable (see side note below)?

According to [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html): `/proc/[pid]/environ` contains the initial environment variables (which won't be changed even if the program itself changes the envrionment variables inside) including `PWD` and `PATH`.

Therefore:
if the path in `cmdline` starts with relative dirname(s), you can use `PWD` (in `/proc/[pid]/environ`) as the base path and resolve the relative path;
if the path in `cmdline` is the name of the program itself, you can loop through each directory in `PATH` (in `/proc/[pid]/environ`) and the target is the *first* file with the same name.

---

Side notes:

`/proc/[pid]/exe` seems to be the dereferenced file (e.g. `/usr/bin/python3.6` instead of `/usr/bin/python3` or `/usr/bin/python` if they are symlinks);

`/proc/[pid]/cmdline` can also contain strange information for some programs so may be unreliable. This seems to be related to the program but not the kernel, and I didn't observe any python scripts behaving this way (and editing `sys.argv` in python doesn't seem to affect `/proc/[pid]/cmdline`). [My question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367593/how-to-get-the-full-executable-name-of-a-running-process-in-linux) also talked a bit about this.

Answer (score 0):

Experimentally, for bash, `/proc/{pid}/fd/255` is a link to the full path of the executed script.

```
#! /bin/bash

ls -l /proc/$$/fd/255
```

Comment: Because any shell has to process a script line-by-line, the shell process will always have an open handle to the file it reads the script from: in bash it's 255, in dash it's 10, in zsh and ksh it's 11, in yash it's 100, etc. But that's NOT the case in perl or python, which are compiling the whole script at once, and closing the file it was read from before running it.