# Get the full path of running script from /proc

Tags: linux, scripting, proc

If a running script was called directly, as in not by calling its interpreter with the script's path as an argument, how can the full path to script file reliably be retrieved regardless of the interpreter?

Here are ways that *don't* retrieve the script's absolute path:

- `readlink /proc/$PID/exe` returns the path of the *interpreter* if PID ${PID} is a script.
- `cat /proc/$PID/comm` returns the *basename* of the script.
- There is nothing reliable about looking at the contents of `/proc/$PID/cmdline`. These contents can be changed by the running program and the "zeroth" argument is not guaranteed to be an actual path to a script (as when you run `echo $0` while in a terminal session.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/274759/117549

Comment: [What problem are you actually trying to solve?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) What if the script was run with e.g. `sh -c`? What if it was run with `cat script.sh | sh`? What if the script file was deleted, modified or replaced after the interpreter opened it?

Answer (score 0):

The operating system cannot help with this, because the script is just a piece of datum read by the interpreter. An interpreter can consume the body of a script and then close the file, and also manipulate the global argument vector in such a way that there is no trace of the location of the script.

It's up to the scripting language to provide access to the script name, and other features, like for scripts to be able to have their own command line options that are not processed by the interpreter as its own.

If the scripting language doesn't, there may be hack you can do with `/proc`. If you know that the interpreter has the script file open while executing statements from it, and it's always a certain file descriptor number, you may be able to peek at `/proc/self/fd`. E.g this works for me on a particular GNU/Linux system:

```
$ ./shellarg a b c
my name is /home/kaz/junk/shellarg
```

where `shellarg` is:

```
#!/bin/sh

mypath=$(readlink /proc/$$/fd/10)

echo "my name is $mypath"
```

I don't recommend this because it depends on the script being open as file descriptor 10. More importantly, in the case of this particular scrpiting language, it is unecessary, since the shell behaves nicely and installs the script name as `$0`.

If you're using some hostile scripting language that makes it difficult to get the script name, it may be possible to invoke the script via shell wrapper which inserts `$0`:

```
#!/bin/sh

mydir=$(dirname "$0")
fbzfile="$mydir"/script.fbz

frobozz-interpreter -f $fbzfile -- $fbzfile ... other args
```

Here, `frobozz-interpreter` receives the script name as the argument to its `-f`, and keeps it a secret. It parses the whole file and then closes it before running it scanning `/proc` within the script is futile. However, our shell wrapper simply passes the name of the script as the first argument to that script. The script expects that, and all is good.